# Running tomcat in debug mode as a brew service?

Tags: homebrew, remote-debugging, tomcat9

I have got tonnes of articles to run tomcat in debug mode by starting it as a with the startup scripts. I am running tomcat as a brew service on Mac, and using the below command(s) to start/stop the service:

```
brew services start/stop/restart tomcat
```

I also tried adding the jpda startup script in startup.sh with the above method but it didn't work. Still exploring around to see if someone has the solution to this. Meanwhile, if someone can help?

Running Tomcat 9 via Homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine where your tomcat installation is located with `brew list tomcat`.

Then create a `setenv.sh` in the `libexec/bin` folder of your installation. Make sure that the file owner/permissions are set as for the other files in this directory.

In the `setenv.sh`, you can specify the debugging options that you want to set by e.g. adding the following line at the bottom:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=18000"
```

Then restart tomcat and you should be able to connect your debugger to tomcat applications.

Comment: With these settings added my Homebrew-managed Tomcat won't start anymore and the logs are empty (no chance to debug).

Comment: Probably, you overwrote CATALINA_OPTS with only the debugger settings, instead of only adding the parameters to it. I changed the description for setting CATALINA_OPTS. It should now work, if you just add the line given in my response at the bottom of the setenv.sh